# Synchronize directories on remote host

Tags: ansible

I want to make a copy of a directory on my remote host. The task I tried to use is:

```
  - name: copy old core configs to new Solr
    become: yes
    become_user: root
    synchronize:
      src="/usr/local/solr/example/solr/collection1/"
      dest="/usr/local/solr-4.10.4/example/solr/collection1"
      recursive=yes
    delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

But it seemed like it was hanging forever and looking in `iotop` it didn't seem like anything was being copied. What I expect this to do is SSH into the remote host, and do an rsync from one directory to the other. Am I missing something?

Comment: What's the output with `-vvv`?

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing YAML syntax styles by using `=` instead of `:`. In my experience this can cause misleading errors.

Try:

```
- name: copy old core configs to new Solr
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  synchronize:
    src: "/usr/local/solr/example/solr/collection1/"
    dest: "/usr/local/solr-4.10.4/example/solr/collection1"
    recursive: yes
  delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```